# NullPointerException at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.ModeledPageLayout.addStandaloneView

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I try to add several views to my rcp project.

At first I created plugin project with a view using Plugin Project wizard. 
View was added by two extensions: org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions and org.eclipse.ui.views. I started the project and see that view was added successfully.

Then I tried to add several views by the exactly same way. The only difference was that "standalone" property was absent. Views were not added without any errors.

Than I tried to comment the declaration of the initial view and restart the app. Result was the same - new views were not displayed.

Than I add property "standalone=true" to the extensions of other views. 
Аnd get the error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.ModeledPageLayout.addStandaloneView(ModeledPageLayout.java:243)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PerspectiveExtensionReader.processView(PerspectiveExtensionReader.java:289)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PerspectiveExtensionReader.processExtension(PerspectiveExtensionReader.java:112)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PerspectiveExtensionReader.readElement(PerspectiveExtensionReader.java:350)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.registry.RegistryReader.readElements(RegistryReader.java:145)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.registry.RegistryReader.readExtension(RegistryReader.java:156)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.registry.RegistryReader.readRegistry(RegistryReader.java:177)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PerspectiveExtensionReader.extendLayout(PerspectiveExtensionReader.java:76)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.setPerspective(WorkbenchPage.java:4038)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.setup(WorkbenchWindow.java:733)
```

I found this [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=331236). And try to do all the same on Eclipse Mars. Result was the same.

I uncomment declarations of the initial view with "standalone" property and delete "standalone" property from other views. Error disappeared.

I check the code in few generated classes and didn't find any other mentions of the creation or configuration of the initial view.

What other difference may be between a view, which was created by the project wizard, and a view, which was added manually?

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: add view via code in perspective class.

```
layout.addView(View.ID, IPageLayout.TOP, IPageLayout.RATIO_MAX, IPageLayout.ID_EDITOR_AREA);
```

http://vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse3RCP/article.html#add-view-to-perspective-via-code